# What is this MVC pattern: a stub delegate and data source

Tags: ios, cocoa, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I have some view controllers in my program that require some data and direction to run. They have a data source and delegate property that are set when they are initialized *(maybe this is the problem?)*.
After using these for a while, the abstraction is becoming a pain for simple use cases where the data does not change. The pain is that each "caller" needs to implement the standard datasource and delegate methods that these controllers require.

The solution? More abstraction! It is very tempting to make a middle manager and use something like:

```
self.myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
id myVCSimpleDataSourceAndDelegate = [[MyVCSimpleDataSourceAndDelegate alloc] init];
myVCSimpleDataSourceAndDelegate.data = @[1, 2, 3];
myVC.dataSource = myVCSimpleDataSourceAndDelegate;
myVC.delegate = myVCSimpleDataSourceAndDelegate;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:myVC animated:YES];
```

This approach is attractive because, for example, my main view controller deals with several `MyViewController`s, with just a couple different use cases. Currently this makes the majority of code in my main view controller focused on that management, which this would relieve.

The scary part of this approach is that I have not heard of this pattern before and I am leery to invent new kinds of abstractions.

**Is this "middle manager" a known design pattern, or is this approach an MVC anti-pattern?**

Comment: What do you mean by "caller" in: "each caller needs to implement the standard datasource and delegate methods that these controllers require"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you have anything to worry about. There is a great article on objc.io which deals with exactly this issue. Take a look here: http://www.objc.io/issue-1/lighter-view-controllers.html

Also, to answer your question directly I don't think that it's a named pattern but rather a design principle called "Separation of Concerns": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns